# firebase reinitialize recaptcha to use with others callbacks

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to reinitialize firebase -> recaptcha (allready loaded and initialisated) to use with other callbacks ?

```
function my_recaptcha(my_success_callback,my_expired_callback){

    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('id_container_recaptcha', {
        'size': 'invisible',
        'callback': function(response) {
            // reCAPTCHA solved, allow user to do action.
            // ... 
            my_success_callback.call(this,arguments);
        },
        'expired-callback': function() {
         // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
         // ...
            my_expired_callback.call(this,arguments);
        }

    });
}
```

If I try some like this

```
my_recaptcha(function(){
    console.log('SUCCES 1')
},function(){
    console.log('EXPIRED 1')
})

my_recaptcha(function(){
    console.log('SUCCES 2')
},function(){
    console.log('EXPIRED 2')
})
```

I got this error:

> Uncaught Error: ReCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

Even if I try before `grecaptcha.reset(window.recaptchaWidgetId);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To re-instantiate a reCAPTCHA in the same element container, you have to clear it first: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier#clear

This allows you to reinstantiate a new reCAPTCHA.
`window.recaptchaVerifier.clear()`